# 1 IntelliSense: expected a ')' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\crtdefs.h 551 13 - Visual Studio Error while building

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I am trying to build a solution and I am getting the following error.

IntelliSense: expected a ')' in crtdefs.h
in the following line:

```
__declspec (__nothrow) void test();
```

There is an error line in "__nothrow".
I am trying to run C code in C++..

Am I missing some Visual C++ directories?? It was working last time when I tried to build solution.

Comment: IntelliSense is notoriously inaccurate. Do you have an actual build error?

Answer (score 1):

In your error list window, do the following:

1. Right click
2. Un-check show intellisense errors
3. Solve other errors in your code and check if re-build succeeds

[image]

If it succeeds, you can continue ignoring intellisense errors.

4. Sometimes it can be annoying to work with intellisense tell you that
   your code is wrong. You can also disable intellisense error
   reporting using:

   tools -> options -> text editor -> c/c++ -> Advanced -> Disable Error Reporting

[image]

Change this to **true** and the errors will stop getting shown.

5) as you have specifically mentioned,

> I am trying to run C code in C++.

In case you have headers like `stdlib` in your C code, change it to `cstdlib` in C++.

Look for other name changes that need to be done for header file names. Check out the seciton on deprecated header from the followign link: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header

Please let me know what solved your problem afterwards. :)

Comment: thank you for your kind reply..i did what u said but when I am trying to build solution it says build failed...:(

Comment: then you might be missing a header file or library in your project.

Comment: I thought so too but how to know what header file or library I am missing??

Comment: put the list of headers you are using in your question, maybe someone smarter on SO will know which header exactly needs changing.

Comment: is it possible to send you my .cpp file??

Comment: a better option is to do (1) Stack Exchange -> code review.